# Why do I get an InvalidCastException when using Show-ControlPanelItem in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, window

When having the command `Show-ControlPanelItem -CanonicalName Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage` in a PowerShell Script and calling the script from *Windows PowerShell V5.1.19041.2673* I get the following error:

```
+     Show-ControlPanelItem -CanonicalName Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Show-ControlPanelItem], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowControlPanelItemCommand
```

When calling `Show-ControlPanelItem -CanonicalName Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage` first and then calling the script it works. Can someone tell me why that is and/or how I "fix" that.

When running the following command `Set-Content c:\temp\control.ps1 "Show-ControlPanelItem -CanonicalName Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage"; powershell -NoProfile C:\temp\control.ps1`  the control panel is show but when creating the script by hand it does not work anymore.

I also tried calling the original script with `powershell -NoProfile` but that does not work either.

Here is the whole script. What it's supposed to do is change the language of a computer and copy the settings to the welcome screen and for new users.

```
using namespace System.Globalization

function SendKey {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$key
    )

    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($key)
}

function Set-InputLanguage {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$languageTag
    )
    
    Write-Output "trying to set input language"

    $language = Get-WinUserLanguageList | Where-Object {$_.LanguageTag -like $languageTag}
    
    if ($null -ne $language) {
        $languageID = $language.InputMethodTips.Split(":")[1]
        Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload" -Name 1 -Value "$($languageID)"
    }
}

function SetLanguage() {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$languageTag
    )

    try {
        Set-Culture $languageTag
        Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale $languageTag
        Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language $languageTag
        Set-SystemPreferredUILanguage -Language $languageTag
        Set-InputLanguage $languageTag

        Write-Output "language preferences set successfully"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "language preferences could not be set"
    }
}

function IsLanguageInstalled() {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$languageTag
    )

    $computer = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
    $installedLanguagePacks = $computer.MUILanguages
    
    [int]$index = [array]::IndexOf($installedLanguagePacks.ToLower(), $languageTag)

    if ($index -gt -1) {
        return $true
    }
    return $false
}

function InstallLanguagePack() {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$languageTag
    )

    try {
        $packagePath = "$($PSScriptRoot)\langpacks\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_$($languageTag).cab"
        Add-WindowsPackage -Online -PackagePath $packagePath -NoRestart

        $oldLanugageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
        $oldLanugageList.Insert(0, $languageTag)
        Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $oldLanugageList -Force:$doForce

        return $true
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }

}

function CopyLanguageSettings() {
    Show-ControlPanelItem -CanonicalName Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage
    add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000

    SendKey -key '+{TAB}'
    SendKey -key '{RIGHT}'
    SendKey -key '{TAB}'
    SendKey -key '{ENTER}'
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000 
    SendKey -key '{TAB}'
    SendKey -key ' '
    SendKey -key '{TAB}'
    SendKey -key ' '
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000 
    #SendKey -key '{ENTER}'
}

function InstallLanguage {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$languageTag
    )

    $languageTag = $languageTag.ToLower()
    [bool]$isLanguageInstalled = IsLanguageInstalled -languageTag "en-gb"

    if ($isLanguageInstalled = $false) {
        InstallLanguagePack -languageTag "en-gb"
    }

    $isLanguageInstalled = IsLanguageInstalled -languageTag $languageTag

    if ($isLanguageInstalled) {
        Write-Output "Language: $languageTag already installed"
        Write-Output "trying to set language preferences"
        SetLanguage -languageTag $languageTag
        Write-Output "trying to copy language preferences"
        CopyLanguageSettings
        #Restart-Computer
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "trying to install language: $languageTag"
        $isLanguageInstalledSuccessfully = InstallLanguagePack -languageTag $languageTag
    
        if ($isLanguageInstalledSuccessfully) {
            Write-Output "language installed successfully"
            Write-Output "trying to set language preferences"
            SetLanguage -languageTag $languageTag
            Write-Output "trying to copy language preferences"
            CopyLanguageSettings
            #Restart-Computer
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "language could not be installed"
        }
    }
}

InstallLanguage -languageTag $args[0]
```

Comment: Just as a point of reference: in v5.1.22621.963, I do _not_ see the problem. When the error surfaces, does it still open Control Panel, or does it fail completely?

Comment: @mklement0 In the script it fails completely otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: And you're invoking this script directly, in-session? Does it also fail if you place the command as _the only one_ in a script?

Comment: Works fine here as well with ```PS> set-content c:\temp\control.ps1 "Show-ControlPanelItem -CanonicalName Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage"; powershell -NoProfile C:\temp\control.ps1``` - (psversion  5.1.19041.2673). Might be related so something else in the script loading a conflicting assembly versions?

Comment: @mklement0 I tried it with only having the ```Show-ControlPanelItem``` in a script and then calling it from the Windows Powershell as admin. I still get the same exception.

Comment: @mclayton When creating a script with ```Show-ControlPanelItem``` and calling it from Windows Powershell as admin it does not work. But when calling your command it works without problem. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Does the script contain *just* the ```Show-ControlPanelItem``` or any other commands? You could try calling Powershell with e.g.  ```powershell.exe c:\temp\myscript.ps1 -NoProfile``` - update your *question* with the results rather than post in comments…

Comment: Wild guess - does the script still work if you remove ```Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Globalization```? I’m pretty sure System.Globalization is available by default *without* having to load the assembly, so that might be loading a different version of the assembly and causing the cast exception…

Comment: @mclayton the script is "working" but I get the same error as before

Comment: Hmmm. I've tried running your script from a file but with all the ```set-*``` lines disabled as I don't really want to update my system settings, and it shows the "Region" control panel applet fine. - maybe try something similar in your environment and see if you can isolate the minimal script needed to reproduce the issue...

Comment: Also, note the ```-NoProfile``` in my previous comments - you *might* have something in your profile script that causes the issue and it may not be obvious if you're just looking at your sample code. Using ```powershell.exe ... -NoProfile``` will disable any profile scripts and allow you to run a "clean" test...

Comment: @mclayton, good tip re `-NoProfile`, but note that it must be placed _before_ `-File` / `-Command` - the latter being the default in Windows PowerShell. Therefore: `powershell.exe -NoProfile ...` or `powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command ...` or `powershell.exe -NoProfile -File ...`

Comment: @mklement0 - I think I did in my first comment when I tested it, and then got lazy and quoted it (wrongly) from memory. Worth pointing out for other readers though :-).